# Is there a way to freeze Table columns and Table Row in Android Table

Tags: android, css, row, android-tablelayout

I need to know can I freeze first Table Row and first Table Column inside a Table Layout while scrolling horizontal and vertically.

When I scroll horizontally, the columns for should get frozen.
When I scroll vertically, the header or table header or first row should get frozen.

Kindly reply, if there is any api for this.

I am using dynamic table for this, i.e. I load rows while executing the webservice and loading number of rows depending on the hit .

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with default properties of table layout.
you will have to customize your view to create headers and fixed columns separately.

here is an [example](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/08/android-scroll-table-fixed-header-column.html)

Comment: Can you scroll to last row's last column , I think so no .. its limited , I have gone through video

Comment: may you should try fixing it thn ;)

Comment: I need some way . I think google Android people should integrate a new class in their api for this . Some thing that excel does

Comment: I check out . it does scrolls , but I have a more customisable table